# refresh div content after x seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

Curious when executing this block of code for example

```
function upsh() {
    // Assuming we have #box
    $('#live').load('time.php');
}

setInterval("upsh()", 30000);
```

is there a synchronous way to execute this code this seems to work great for a minute then it seems to over request till it kills wamp.   trying to live refresh a div with or should  code be expect to make so many requests   30 seconds should be  2 request a minute not hundreds right?  seems to work great for one minute then unclear why more then 2 requests per minute. thanks if you can explain

[request overkill?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECfV7.png)

Comment: seems `time.php` request is taking more time than 30sec. You could use callback method to schedule next request.  `function upsh(){
$('#live').load('time.php', function(){ setTimeout(upsh, 30000)});
}
upsh()`

Comment: Ignoring what you have here, what exactly are you trying to accomplish, there may be a better way to do it?

Comment: Very hard to understand the question as written. But I've seen this sort of thing happen (if I understand the problem) when more than one interval gets set somehow. Are you making sure that you are either A) setting only one interval, and that no other interval is getting set while that interval is live, or B) that you are wiping the current interval before setting a new one? However, it would seem to me that perhaps thinking in terms of async returns and Promises to refresh your view might be more "promising" (haha).

Comment: @TimConsolazio may have nailed it.  If your interval is loading the current page, then you get a new interval each time the page loads.  Each interval is trying to load the page...

Comment: update a div or span ever x seconds  with out a server overload.

Comment: thanks i learn something new ever day    ill give that a try

Comment: @JohnRobbins where is that JavaScript located? Is it re-loaded by any chance every time you reload `time.php`? If so you end up with many intervals each triggering every 30 seconds.

Comment: yes it was on my main page.php in the header but your comment bring me to a new understanding on how this javascript works  thanks everyone